# How to add a behaviour description for different range of template values in Doxygen?

Tags: c++, templates, doxygen

Is there a "common" way to add a list of behaviours for different range of template values in Doxygen ?

For example with :

```
template<int Var> class MyClass{};
```

I would describe the behaviour for Var < 0, Var = 0 and Var > 0. How to present that clearly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [tparam](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdtparam) to document the template parameter.

If it does not fit there, I probably would use the [par](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdpar) command to describe the behaviour inside the class documentation.